# link a test-class to its main class

Tags: unit-testing, junit

I routinely create, for each Java class, a corresponding test class. However, it seems that, from the compiler point of view, they are not linked in any way. Of course I can link them with mutual referrals in Javadoc comments, however, I wonder if there is a more standard way to tell the world "Class A is the JUnit test of class B" and "class B is the main class tested by class A".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't really have any compile-time reference since you typically distribute main code without test code. There is only a naming convention. For a class named `Foo` I use:

- `FooTest` for unit tests
- `FooSomeSpecificPartOrBehaviorTest` for unit tests of only a subset of class behaviors.
- `FooIT` for integration tests

This convention is pretty standard and for example in IntelliJ IDEA <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> allows you to quickly navigate between main and test classes, only based on naming convention.

Answer (score 1):

Usually the "connection" between the class under test and the test class is established via a **naming convention**: `SHA1DigestTest` contains the test for the `SHA1Digest` class.